# a very simple php calculator that would not perform math operation :(

Tags: php, html, math, calculator, operation

I am trying to create a simple calculator (this is probably superrrr simple but couldn't find the mistake :( sigh* ), so when I hit submit that number 1 and number 2 will perform the operation that the user selected. But the answer won't echo when submitted :( What is the problem? Thank you so much!

```
<?php
if ($_POST['subBtn']) { 
$number1 = $_POST['number1'];
$number2 = $_POST['number2'];

if($_POST['group1'] == 'add') {
echo $number1 + $number2 = $answer;
}
else if($_POST['group1'] == 'subtract') {
echo $number1 - $number2 = $answer;
}
else if($_POST['group1'] == 'times') {
echo $number1 * $num2ber = $answer;
} 
else if($_POST['group1'] == 'divide') {
echo $number2 / $number2 = $answer;

echo "<p>" . $answer . " </p>"; 
}
}
?>

<form name="number1" action="activity-2-4.php" method="post">
number1:<select name="number1">
<option value="0">0</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="9">9</option>
<option value="10">10</option>
        </select><br>

number2:<select name="number2">
<option value="0">0</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="9">9</option>
<option value="10">10</option>
        </select><br>
<input type="radio" name="group1" id="add" value="add">+<br/>
<input type="radio" name="group1" id="subtract" value="subtract">-<br/>
<input type="radio" name="group1" id="times" value="times">x<br/>
<input type="radio" name="group1" id="divide" value="divide">/<br/>
<button type="submit" name="subBtn" id="answer" value="answer">Calculate</button>
</form>
```

Comment: $answer should be on the left side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't assign values to variables in an echo statement. Moreover, the variable the value is being assigned to, should always be on the left. In addition, your echo was inside the last elseif from the divide.

Try this instead:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['subBtn']) && isset($_POST['group1'])) { 
    $number1 = isset($_POST['number1']) ? $_POST['number1'] : 0;
    $number2 = isset($_POST['number2']) ? $_POST['number2'] : 0;

    switch ($_POST['group1']) {
        case 'add':
            $answer = $number1 + $number2;
            break;
        case 'subtract':
            $answer = $number1 - $number2;
            break;
        case 'times':
            $answer = $number1 * $number2;
            break;
        case 'divide':
            $answer = $number2 / $number2;
            break;
        default:
            $answer = 'No operation method selected.';
            break;
    }

    echo "<p>" . $answer . " </p>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Also Explain him the wrong variable used in 'times', wrong calculation in 'divide'.

Comment: @Devs: You're right. Done, also some refactoring of his code.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is your problem:

```
echo $number2 / $number2 = $answer
```

Change it to:

```
$answer = $number2 / $number2
```

And the same on each math operation.

You are trying to display something at the same time as you store the data, but in the wrong order.

You already have an echo of the answer after the math part.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the POST variable exists or not.

The calculations ,variables and echo you are using wrongly `echo $number1 + $number2 = $answer;` I guess your expected output `4+1=5` in this format.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['subBtn'])) 
{ 
    $number1 = isset($_POST['number1']) ? $_POST['number1'] : '';
    $number2 = isset($_POST['number2']) ? $_POST['number2'] : '';
    $group1  = isset($_POST['group1']) ? $_POST['group1'] : '';

    $answer  = '';
    $stmt    = '';

    switch ($group1)
    {
        case 'add': 
            $stmt   = $number1.'+'.$number2.'= ';
            $answer = $number1 + $number2;
        break;

        case 'subtract':    
            $stmt   = $number1.'-'.$number2.'= ';
            $answer = $number1 - $number2;
        break;

        case 'times':   
            $stmt   = $number1.'*'.$number2.'= ';
            $answer = $number1 * $number2;
        break;

        case 'divide':  
            $stmt   = $number1.'/'.$number2.'= ';
            $answer = $number1 / $number2;
        break;
    }

    echo "<p>" . $stmt.$answer . " </p>"; 
}
?>

<form name="number1" action="activity-2-4.php" method="post">
number1:<select name="number1">
<option value="0">0</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="9">9</option>
<option value="10">10</option>
        </select><br>

number2:<select name="number2">
<option value="0">0</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="9">9</option>
<option value="10">10</option>
        </select><br>
<input type="radio" name="group1" id="add" value="add">+<br/>
<input type="radio" name="group1" id="subtract" value="subtract">-<br/>
<input type="radio" name="group1" id="times" value="times">x<br/>
<input type="radio" name="group1" id="divide" value="divide">/<br/>
<button type="submit" name="subBtn" id="answer" value="answer">Calculate</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The $_POST global variable stores everything as a string.
Theoretically PHP does type juggling in the back end and converts it to a number but this is not happening for you i don't know which version of PHP you are running. So you could explicitly convert it your self. 
Try this

```
$number1 = (float)$_POST['number1'];
$number2 = (float)$_POST['number2'];
```

if you know you are getting an int you could do

```
$number1 = (int)$_POST['number1'];
$number2 = (int)$_POST['number2'];
```

However I think your problem is with group1.

```
print_r($_POST);
```

make sure you have group1 in there and make sure its exactly the same lowercase values since you are checking in lowercase and this operation is case sensitive.

Then next step would be to print something on the screen and make sure you are in the if to start with

```
echo "i'm in the add case";
```

and so on

Answer (score -1):

Change the way you assign values. change

```
  $number1 + $number2 = $answer;
```

To

```
  $answer = $number1 + $number2;
```